# How to extend the search of ctrl+p in sublime text

Tags: search, sublimetext3

I want to have a universal folder from where I can just use ctrl+p(Quick-open files by name) and get that file.
For example the universal folder is here-> folder1/folder2/templates
and I am in suppose folder3/round-719.. so from here I want to use ctrl+P and then be able to access the files from ../templates

Note: I can use snippets, but according to my use, it isn't very effective. So, it would be good to have this sort of feature.

Comment: So why not add `folder1/folder2/templates` to your project so it appears in the sidebar? It should also appear in `Goto Anything` as well.

Comment: I will be having different folders so its going to be kind of irritating to copy paste the folder every time i create a new one. So, I was looking for something more convenient..